# Ubuntu 14.04.5 Video Freezes When Going Forward or Backwards

Tags: drivers, video, vlc, playback

I'm using 14.04.5 updated fully and like it so far.

Videos work mostly fine, but if I move to a different time in the video, there is a 3-5 seconds freeze where I see both the new and old frames together before the new frames are played.

This happens with the native player and with `VLC`.

I tried looking for "Additional Drivers" but I get no suggestions (even though I checked the repositories etc.).

RAM is `4GB`, laptop is `TP W500` with dedicated and integrated, have had no such issues on Win 7.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2115
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV635/M86 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2126
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Did I phrase the question wrong? Does anyone have any insight into how to solve this issue? Thanks!